# Which you think is better ? Vue ui design

Tags: javascript, vue.js, user-interface, design-patterns, vue-component

Context: App that handles multi role.
A view that in the template has a lot of conditioned rendering.

a) It is better to have a lot of conditioned rendering on the template of a single view ?

b) Have a view for each role and condition it accordingly ?

If I choose option a) I would only have one component with the template very conditioned. I would avoid repeating code, but it would be difficult to maintain and scale if tomorrow I want to add 10 more roles.

If I choose option b) I would be keeping the code readable, maintainable, easy to scale. But I would be repeating a lot of  code.

Personally I would choose option b) and sacrifice the time to write more code but that keep the project tidy up.

What do you think ? Another alternative to handle this scenario will be appreciated. Regards!

Comment: What code will be repeated in case b)?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6gp5fvct/ check this fiddle i write an example for you. Thanks for answer !

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use a dynamic component along with mixins where you can place your repeatable code.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to use Option B, but to remove redundant codes:

1. Use [mixins](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/mixins.html)
2. Convert repeatable components to smaller components